# Is there a way to remove characters in a string in python

Tags: python

I'm making a calculator in python to learn functions and I want to take user input and reduce string length to 3 characters for easier use.

The code I'm trying is:

```
func2 = func[0:] + func[1:] + func[2:]
```

In this example func = mult, And I want func2 = mul, But it outputs multultlt

Comment: `func2 = func[0:3]` ? `func[i:]` means everything from index `i` until the end.

Comment: `func[:3]` to take first 3 characters. `func[i:]` means take from `i`th index to the end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `func = "mult"` then `func[:-1]`returns "mul". In your example you are selecting first the whole string then appending the string without the first letter ("ult") and then appending the string without the first 2 letters ("lt") which is why you get what you get.

As @Ch3steR also suggested if you always want the first 3 characters then `func[:3]` will do that.

Answer (score 2):

in order to get the first 3 characters:

```
func[:3]
```

`func[i:]` - take from i character to the end